# Using Java 7 closure syntax in Eclipse 3.7.1

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, eclipse-indigo

I have java SDK 7 installed and i am using Eclipse 3.7.1 Indigo.

When i use the new Java 7 syntax for defining a HashMap, it works fine.

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

But when i try to use closure syntax, eclipse throws compile errors. This is what i am trying to compile.

```
    public static <T> Collection<T> select(Collection<T> source,
                                       {T=>Boolean} predicate) {

    Collection<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T o : source) {
        if (predicate.invoke(o)) {
            result.add(o);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Is the syntax wrong? or Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Also, the syntax is wrong. The syntax of the formal parameter would just be `Predicate<T> predicate`, the use of the predicate would be `if (predicate.test(o))`, and the actual parameter at the call site, with a List<Person> called people as the collection, would be something like `select(people, p -> p.isHappy() && p.isSinging());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Java 7 doesn't have closures - it's a planned feature for Java 8.

It was *hoped* that it would be in Java 7, but it didn't make the cut.